# receiving GLib-GObject-WARNING signal 'activate' is invalid for instance

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm trying to create a simple Menu widget with GTK3+, the program complies but I get this warning at runtime:

`(menu: 2320): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:40:48.620: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'activate' is invalid for instance '0x557d45672290' of type 'GtkWindow'`

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate_about(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;

    GtkWidget *menubar;
    GtkWidget *fileMenu;
    GtkWidget *fileMi;
    GtkWidget *quitMi;
    GtkWidget *about;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Simple menu");

    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 12);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
    fileMenu = gtk_menu_new();

    fileMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("File");
    quitMi = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");
    about = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("About");

    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(fileMi), fileMenu);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), about);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(fileMenu), quitMi);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), fileMi);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
    G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quitMi), "activate",
    G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "activate",
    G_CALLBACK(activate_about), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

static void activate_about(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {

    const gchar *authors[] = {"ad Chi", NULL};

    gtk_show_about_dialog(GTK_WINDOW(window),
                    "program-name", "jjkjk",
                    "version", "0.0.1",
                    "copyright", "(C) 2017 ad Chi",
                    "license-type", GTK_LICENSE_GPL_3_0,
                    "website", "https://github.com/kjk",
                    "comments", "Totally kj",
                    "authors", authors,
                    "documenters", NULL,
                    "logo-icon-name", "start-here",
                    "title", "About kj kj",
                    NULL);

    return;
}
```

I'm confused by this warnings. Can anyone explain how I might have come about triggering them, and how they would be able to be debugged in gdb? I tried to use G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings ./a.out
but it is not very informative.

Comment: When you run your program in a debugger and step through it, which line causes the message?

Comment: Imagine You have a Dog called Rex and a friend called Tim. Both of them are outside in garden and you call Tim inside, but instead of Tim you get Yourself with the Dog.
Why should that work?

Comment: GtkWindow does not have The activate Signal. Check its documentation -> https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow.signals.

Comment: If you need a Dialog to be opened, that is not the way you do it. I have a playlist on my Youtube Channel about Dialogs. =>> https://www.youtube.com/c/MichaelB-GTK

Comment: The right calls are: g_signal_connect( window, "destroy",
                      gtk_main_quit, NULL ); and g_signal_connect( quitMi, "activate",
                      G_CALLBACK( activate_about ), NULL ).: But they are not going to fix your Dialog approach. Because now the Quit button runs the Dialog .

Comment: You do need to cast to those objects to G_OBJECT inside og g_signal_connect_*()and definitely you do not need to cast gtk_main_quit to G_CALLBACK, because gtk_main_quit() match with the needed callback signature.

Comment: Do you mean g_signal_connect( G_OBJECT( about ), "activate", G_CALLBACK( activate_about ), NULL );?

Comment: one last thing. If you do not use gpointer data then use g_signal_connect_swapped( object, "signal", callback_func, object ); , where the first argument object should be the same  with the last one and use only one parameter for the signature of your callback. Like this:  void callback_func ( GtkWidget *widget ){}. You see no gpointer data parameter is present. Have Fun with GTK

Comment: The GtkMenuItem does have the activate signal which behaves like clicked signal in this case, but you still need to take care for transient. Just check my GtkDialog and GtkAboutDialog Playlists.

Comment: [Check the changes I did to your program](https://pastebin.com/raw/ujX9YWEa)  and compare with your program.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting the `activate_about` handler to the `window` instance, instead of connecting it to the `about` menu item. A `GtkWindow` does not have an `activate` signal.

Additionally, you do not need to cast the first argument of `g_signal_connect()` to `GObject`.

Comment: Yes, he was trying to monitor the [activate](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuItem.html#GtkMenuItem-activate) signal from [GtkMenuItem](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuItem.html#GtkMenuItem). He probably needs `g_signal_connect_swapped ( about, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( activate_about ), window )`